# How to run Spring Boot Application as a Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have deployed my web application on company server by executing jar files then the project is running fine.But when i close the jar and again try to run the project on browser then client is not able to access the application.I want solution on this  that if i close the jar then also client can access the application.

Comment: We need to run jar file as background service....

Comment: how we can achieve this using windows command prompt.. what command should i have to give?

Comment: On windows you need to install your applcation [as a service](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot-daemon).

Comment: Please check the official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this simple command to run a jar file as background service...

```
 javaw -jar test.jar
```

after run this command you could not detect any change in cmd...and can close your command prompt.  after 1 or 2 minute enter your URL in browser  .. you will see your web program is running...

before run this command must be stop previously running jar for avoid same port conflict

[for more details](http://windowsbulletin.com/files/exe/oracle-corporation/java-7-update-55/javaw-exe)

Answer (score 1):

When you close the `cmd` prompt, your java application will also be killed. To keep the java application running after closing the terminal you have to use the below command.

```
nohup java -jar app_name.jar &
```

just replace the `app_name` with your application name and run the command.

Comment: you are welcome 
please tell me what happened after running the command

Comment: i am using nohup command on windows and this displaying an error "nohup is not recognized as a internal or external command" .. now what should i do??